# How to get IntPtr from byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pass a `byte[]` to a method takes a `IntPtr` Parameter in C#, is that possible and how?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Why would you want to do it?

Comment: You need this if you use DirectShow API for example... to get data from VideoRenderer, you have to use this... and `GCHandle` method works like a charm... also the `fixed` method. :P :))

Comment: You need this for anything that is transferring terrabytes of data and you want to avoid the extra copy. Use your imagination.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Not sure about getting an IntPtr to an array, but you can copy the data for use with unmanaged code by using Mashal.Copy:

```
IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, unmanagedPointer, bytes.Length);
// Call unmanaged code
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
```

Alternatively you could declare a struct with one property and then use Marshal.PtrToStructure, but that would still require allocating unmanaged memory.

**Edit:** Also, as Tyalis pointed out, you can also use *fixed* if unsafe code is an option for you

Comment: Just to clarify, `Marshal.Copy` with that overload needs a start index. The call should be `Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, unmanagedPointer, bytes.Length);`

Comment: better to get IntPtr without creating new memory, like @user65157's answer.

Comment: I had to copy my managed memory to unmanaged memory to get the unmanaged code to execute correctly.

Answer (score 231):

Another way,

```
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(byteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
// Do your stuff...
pinnedArray.Free();
```

Comment: @Cipi Per one of Eric Lipperts other post, this should have the Fixed keyword instead of using the GC

Comment: thanks a lot. Work nice and its pretty easy. I am not so skilled in GCHandles and Marshal. Can someone say me what pluses have the Marshal and what the GCHandle and where use which one? Thanks

Comment: Could someone please provide the reference to the Eric Lippert post?

Comment: @piggy: I think the disadvantage of Marshal is that you have to make a copy of your data (which can take a long time and waste memory you might need)

Comment: @makerofthings7 I do not believe Lippert is saying to use 'fixed' instead of the GC [to pin objects], I believe he is saying do not use the GC to pin an object indefinitely, along with saying do not use fixed to do the same, either.

Answer (score 153):

The following should work but **must** be used within an `unsafe` context:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
fixed (byte* p = buffer)
{
    IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)p;
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

**Beware:** you have to use the pointer within the `fixed` block. The GC can move the object once you are no longer within the `fixed` block.

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't involve allocating extra memory just to access the data

Comment: This is the best answer if large byte[] are used.  A copy has too much overhead

Comment: This then leaves me with "Unable to read memory" on the byte[]. Is there a go to solution for this?

Answer (score 20):

You could use [`Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.unsafeaddrofpinnedarrayelement) to get a memory pointer to the array (or to a specific element in the array). Keep in mind that the array must be pinned first as per the API documentation:

> The array must be pinned using a [GCHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle) before it is passed to this method. For maximum performance, this method does not validate the array passed to it; this can result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: This is - I think - the only way to get an IntPtr for an array element which is not the 0th (without using unsafe code).

Comment: To make this code reliable array should be pinned first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k4y07x3.aspx

Answer (score 16):

Here's a twist on @user65157's answer (+1 for that, BTW):

I created an IDisposable wrapper for the pinned object:

```
class AutoPinner : IDisposable
{
   GCHandle _pinnedArray;
   public AutoPinner(Object obj)
   {
      _pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   }
   public static implicit operator IntPtr(AutoPinner ap)
   {
      return ap._pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject(); 
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
      _pinnedArray.Free();
   }
}
```

then use it like thusly:

```
using (AutoPinner ap = new AutoPinner(MyManagedObject))
{
   UnmanagedIntPtr = ap;  // Use the operator to retrieve the IntPtr
   //do your stuff
}
```

I found this to be a nice way of not forgetting to call Free() :)

Comment: You may want to investigate deriving your AutoPinner from SafeHandle since that class takes concurrency and security "gotchas" into account, as well as encouraging/using the recommended IDisposable pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Marshal.Copy works but is rather slow. Faster is to copy the bytes in a for loop. Even faster is to cast the byte array to a ulong array, copy as much ulong as fits in the byte array, then copy the possible remaining 7 bytes (the trail that is not 8 bytes aligned). Fastest is to pin the byte array in a fixed statement as proposed above in Tyalis' answer.

Answer (score -6):

In some cases you can use an Int32 type (or Int64) in case of the IntPtr. If you can, another useful class is BitConverter. For what you want you could use BitConverter.ToInt32 for example.

Comment: **You should never, ever use Int32 or Int64 in place of a pointer**. If you have to port your code to a different platform (32-bit->64-bit), you'll have all kinds of headaches.

Comment: No, there's no valid case in which you can correctly and safely use an `Int32` as a pointer. This was a bad practice done years ago and it lead to all kinds of porting issues. Even an `Int64` isn't safe because there are already 128-bit architectures and pointer size will increase. Pointers should only ever be represented as pointers.

Comment: I used it in .NET CF projects without issues, of course you'd have problems if you try to port it to other systems, but there is code out there not meant to be ever ported.

Comment: It's true that some code is not planned to be ported but things can change pretty quickly. Even if your usage on the CF was justified (I don't know) it's still bad advice to a generic question. The only valid scenario for using `int` / `long` for pointers is when the language used has no concept of them (for example VB6). C# supports pointers and has `IntPtr` - there's no need at all to use an `int` in place of a pointer ever. I'll remove my -1 if you add clear warnings and an explanation of potential issues to your answer.

Comment: I do not care about the -1 but about the "never, ever" :-)

Comment: In .NET CF for example there weren't all the options for marshalling data that the full framework has, and that option offered a simple option, though to be fair now it doesn't really matter much anymore unless you develop for rugged devices, as that platform is dead; but this is a 2009 question.

Comment: Well, you _are_ comparing the usage of very specific marshalling code to this general question about using pointers in C#. In normal C# there's no scenario where this would be valid. I know it's an old question but I voted it down because I came across it by looking for the way to allocate memory for an IntPtr - others will see this, too. I see your advice as very dangerous because people will go with it thinking they got away with solving a problem easily when all they got is future trouble.