# Passing binary data to c# from matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing

I have C# interfaces to a proprietary (internal) image processing library.

Interfaces look something like this:

```
void RGBConvert::ConvertFromRGBToYCbCr(                   
    int            ncols,        
    int            nrows,        
    IntPtr         rgb,         
    IntPtr         out)
```

Where IntPtr is a pointer to the underlying memory.  I have called .NET objects many times from Matlab, but passing large C data arrays into C# is not something I've done, and am reaching a dead end.

The Matlab manual: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-net-data-in-matlab_bte9oxc-1.html#bte9o7y-1 indicates that IntPtr is not supported.  By which I mean, it doesn't covert an array of Unsigned8Bit integers into an IntPtr to pass to the method.  (If you construct an IntPtr through some other mechanisms, Matlab will treat it like any other .NET object and pass it around.)  So, how do I find a pointer to the Matlab data, and pass it to this method?

Clearly, one approach would be to use the normal Matlab C/C++ interfaces to "trick" matlab into revealing the pointer to the underlying array data structure, and then pass that pointer to the IntPtr constructor.  Then pass the IntPtr on.  We had hoped to have a "pure" C# implementation, and to not have to have a C/C++ interface in addition to the C# interface.

Another avenue might be to take the Matlab `ConvertArray` call, to convert a matlab array to a .NET array, but then I still need an IntPtr pointing at the raw data.

I don't mind extraneous memory copies here, this is not performance critical code, this is experimentation code.

Anyone have experience with this issue, and recommendations?

Thoughts?

Comment: the documentation doesn't state that IntPtr is not supported. It says "The following primitive .NET argument types do not have direct MATLAB equivalent types. MATLAB passes these types as is."

Comment: @Bond reworded IntPtr not supported comment, hopefully that makes it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the address of the MathLab array you'd better wrap the 3rd Party API with a method that takes(and returns) an array

```
byte[] ConvertFromRGBToYCbCr(int ncols, int nrows, byte[] rgb)
```

then get the address of this array in .net with a technique like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537722/842543) to call the original RGBConvert method.