# C# Convert object to unsafe void*

Tags: c#, unsafe

I'm trying to convert an `object` to an unsafe `void*`. Here's an example :

```cs
public static void glBufferData(uint target, ulong size, object data, uint usage)
{
    _glBufferData(target, size, data, usage);
}
```

Here are the parameters of `_glBufferData` :

```cs
uint target, ulong size, void* data, uint usage
```

I'm passing this object :

```cs
float[] positions =
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.0f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f
};
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```cs
fixed (void* ptr = &data)
{
}
```

My class is unsafe by the way. 
How can I do that ?

Comment: I don't know if it's a dupe necessarily, but maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527985/what-is-void-in-c) will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take the address of a variable of type `object`.

Change the type of the `data` parameter from `object` to `float[]` and use `fixed` to obtain the address of the first array element:

```
private static extern void _glBufferData(uint target, ulong size, void* data, uint usage);

public static void glBufferData(uint target, ulong size, float[] data, uint usage)
{
    fixed (float* ptr = &data[0])
    {
        _glBufferData(target, size, ptr, usage);
    }
}
```

You can also try changing `void*` to `float[]` in the signature of the `_glBufferData` method, which would eliminate the need to use `fixed`:

```
private static extern void _glBufferData(uint target, ulong size, float[] data, uint usage);

public static void glBufferData(uint target, ulong size, float[] data, uint usage)
{
    _glBufferData(target, size, ptr, usage);
}
```

Comment: It's working, thank you. The downside is that I have to precise the type of the variable. Is there no other way do to that ?

Comment: With the first solution I posted, you can create additional overloads of `glBufferData` for each data type you need. All of them can call `_glBufferData`.

Comment: This is what I'm gonna do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a GCHandle for your object

```
IntPtr handle = (IntPtr) GCHandle.Alloc(this)
```

2. Parse your handle as void*

```
glBufferData(target, size, (void*)handle, usage)
```

3. Restore your object from the InPtr GCHandle

```
public static void glBufferData(uint target, ulong size, void* data, uint usage)
{
            GCHandle myObjectHandle = (GCHandle)((IntPtr)data);
            MyObject obj = (MyObject)myObjectHandle.Target;
}
```