# marshal c struct to c#

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, typedef

Does any body can marshal this part of c/c++ code in c# please?

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE    bCommandCode;
    BYTE    bParameterCode;

    struct
    {
        DWORD   dwSize;
        LPBYTE  lpbBody;
    }
    Data;
}
COMMAND, *LPCOMMAND;
```

thanks a lot

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

First off, declare the above struct as a managed struct - something like:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct SomeStruct
    {
        byte bCommandCode;
        byte bParameterCode;

        SomeOtherStruct otherStruct;

        Data Data;
    }

    struct SomeOtherStruct
    {
        uint dwSize;
        byte lpBody;
    }

    struct Data
    {
    }
```

Though you may have to use the `MarshalAs` attribute here and there to ensure it's actually marshalling them as their proper types. If you want to then read this struct from memory for example, you could do something like:

```
        var bytes = ReadBytes(address, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeStruct)), isRelative);

        fixed (byte* b = bytes)
            return (T) Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(b), typeof (SomeStruct));
```

I am assuming you want to read your struct from memory and marshal it into a managed struct, because otherwise you wouldn't even need the `Marshal` at all. Also, make sure to compile the above code with `/unsafe` enabled.

Comment: Then just change lpBody to a `byte[]` and you should be fine. Do specify a length of the byte array though, otherwise stuff may go south.

Comment: struct Data {} is quite a strange declaration. In the question "Data" is the name of inner structure

Comment: I can't derive what should be in the `Data` struct from the code he posted, you should of course add members to it and marshal them properly with the `[MarshalAs]` attribute and specify a `SizeConst` if required.

Answer (score 0):

```
//01. Declare 'Command' structure
public struct Command
{
    public byte CommandCode;
    public byte ParameterCode;
    public struct Data
    {
        public uint Size;
        public IntPtr Body;
    }
    public Data SendData;
}    

//02. Create & assign an instance of 'Command' structure 
//Create body array
byte[] body = { 0x33, 0x32, 0x34, 0x31, 0x30 };

//Get IntPtr from byte[] (Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537573/how-to-get-intptr-from-byte-in-c-sharp)
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(body, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

//Create command instance
var command = new CardReaderLib.Command
                  {
                      CommandCode = 0x30,
                      ParameterCode = 0x30,
                      SendData = {
                          Size = (uint) body.Length, 
                          Body = pointer
                      }
                  };

//do your stuff

if (pinnedArray.IsAllocated)
    pinnedArray.Free();
```