# Read a C++ struct written to a file with C# code

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling

The system we will be modifying consists of a bunch of applications that communicate via files (some write fils, others read them and so on). The applications are written in C++, one of them is now to be rewritten to C#. The problem is that this new app needs to read a file that contains a C++ struct written to it by another app using C++ fwrite. I have a C++ library that contains this struct and I guess I can reference it within my C# code but I have no control over the application producing the file.

Will it be possible, and if yes with how big an effort, to read a known C++ struct with a C# code?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379492/marshal-c-struct-to-c-sharp

Comment: How is the struct written to the file? It may be simpler to use a common data-structure like XML for this.

Comment: Am missing what is the problem. If you create same struct in c# with same fields in same order, then read the file and convert it to struct using [Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278827/how-to-convert-a-structure-to-a-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: It might be simpler to use XML but if you read the question carefully then it says "but I have no control over the application producing the file" which means I cannot change the app producing the file. Then chaning the format is not possible

Comment: Define structure in C#, read file into `byte[]`, use [Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4ca6d5z7.aspx). And the problem is?

Comment: Everybody suggests XML, but when you want some textual intermediate form, YAML will be a much better choice.

Comment: @Sinatr : so are you saying I can define a structure with exactly the same fields in my C# code as the structure in this C++ dll and if I read a C++ struct from file and use this Marshal.PtrToStructure then it will magically create a C# struct out of it?

Comment: Yep, this is a right way to go, see example on msdn, it *magically* creates inner structure. Otherwise use manual approach (@Pete's answer).

Answer (score 0):

How many structs and how big? It may be easier, and probably more robust, to just write your own code to read them, something like

```
static ReadFoo (BinaryReader reader)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.thing = reader.ReadInt32();
    ...
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, I read that c++ and C# write data differently (long can have a different size) and you should not just read the data in a custom way... there are marshalling techniques, but I need to know more.

Comment: You should know what your binary exchange standard is. That probably mans freezing it at whatever defacto standard your C++ compiler has been spitting out. Unless you know that you are at the mercy of compiler changes anyway, even wihtout bring a different langauge into it. Once you do know that, you can write your code to read the appropriate fields.