# Get adress of 2d Array to IntPtr in C#

Tags: c#, c, arrays, intptr

I have a c program that I want to reprogram in c#.

In the C program, a function is used which accesses an address of a 2d array.

**Dll.h**

```
int Fg_AddMem(Fg_Struct * Fg, void *pBuffer, const size_t Size, const frameindex_t bufferIndex, dma_mem *memHandle);
```

**Programm.cpp:**

```
#include "Dll.h"
.
.
#define BUFFERS 4
#define BUFFERSIZE(1024*1024)
static char buf[BUFFERS+1][BUFFERSIZE]

for (int i=0; i<BUFFERS; i++)
{
int ret = Fg_AddMem(fg, buf[i], BUFFERSIZE, i, mhead);
.
.
}
```

Now i want to programm it in C#

First, i created a class to import the Dll function over the pInvoker addon

**CAM_SISO.cs:**

```
[DllImport ("fglib5.dll", setLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int Fg_AddMem(IntPtr Fg, IntPtr pBuffer, int size, int bufferIndex, IntPtr memHandle);
```

I'm also created a BackgroundWorker for the for-loop

**Application.cs:**

```
int BufCnt=4;
int Buffersize = 1024*1024;
BackgroundWorker worker_current_add_mem;
.
this.Load += new EventHandler(this.add_mem_backgroundworker);
.
private void add_mem_backgroundworker(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
.
.
worker_current_add_mem.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_Add_mem);
}
.
private void worker_Add_mem(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
char[,]buf = new char[BufCnt+1,Buffersize];
for(int i=0; i<BufCnt; i++)
{
int ret = CAM.SISO.Fg_AddMem(Fg, ??? , Buffersize, i, mHead);
.
.
}
}
```

So now my question is, how can I pass the address of the 2d array to an IntPtr. Also I would like in c, that the array is incremented in the first field to add a memory.

How do I proceed??

I already tried it with GCHandle and Marshal.Copy but nothing works for me.

Comment: `static char buf[BUFFERS+1][BUFFERSIZE]`  why +1?

Comment: You might start here: [How to get IntPtr from bytearray in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537573/how-to-get-intptr-from-byte-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Don't use IntPtr, there is no point.  Declare it as `byte[]` instead.  The pinvoke marshaller takes care of pinning it and generating the pointer.  Your C# code should use a jagged array, a `byte[][]`, to get an equivalent to *buf* in your C++ code.  Technically sbyte but seems unlikely that is what you meant.

Comment: To the `static char buf [BUFFERS + 1] [BUFFERSIZE]` 
I've found a code in the header file which contains this `BUFFERS + 1`
For this reason I have adopted it.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant,
I have changed the code, but it seems to be missing something. An error is displayed, for "invalid argument".
Changing
in CAM_SISO.cs

`[DllImport ("fglib5.dll", setLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

public extern static int Fg_AddMem(IntPtr Fg, byte[] buf, int size, int bufferIndex, IntPtr memHandle);`

in Applications.cs

`private void worker_Add_mem(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
byte [][] buf = new char[BufCnt+1][];
for(int i=0; i<BufCnt; i++)
{
int ret = CAM.SISO.Fg_AddMem(Fg, buf[i] , Buffersize, i, mHead);
}
}`